# Haskell polymorphism and typeclass instance

Tags: haskell, machine-learning, functional-programming, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to write a machine learning library in Haskell, to work on my Haskell skills. 
I thought about a general design involving a class which is like so:

```
  class Classifier classifier where
    train :: X -> y -> trainingData
    classify :: trainingData -> x -> y
```

For example, given a set of examples X, and their true labels y, train returns
trainingData which is used in the classify function.

So, if I want to implement KNN, I would do it like so:

```
data KNN = KNN Int (Int -> Int -> Float)
```

Where the first int is the number of neighbors and the function its the metric that calculate the distance between the vectors

```
  instance Classifier KNN where
---This is where I am stuck---
```

How can I implement the Classifier type class function so they would be generic
to all of the classifier that I will create?
I am feeling like I am treating Haskell too much like an imperative 
OOP like language and I'd like to do this the Haskell way.

Comment: It sounds like you're starting at the problem from the wrong end. Can you post some type signatures of some actual `classify` and `train` functions for the various classifiers you plan on creating? Then it will probably be obvious if, why and how to abstract things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say you need multi-parameter type classes (with optional functional dependencies, or type families; I omit those).

```
 class Classifier c s l  k where
      train :: c -> [(s, l)] -> k
      classify :: c -> k -> s -> l
      combine :: c -> k -> k -> k
```

There is a four-sided relationship between classifier, sample, label and knowledge types.

The train method derives some knowledge (k) from a set of sample (s) — label (l) pairs. The classify method uses that knowledge to infer a label for a sample. (The combine method joins two pieces of knowledge together; don't know if it always applies).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your type class has no knowledge of what a classifier provides, you could do something like

```
class Classifier c where
  train :: [x] -> [y] -> c -> [(x,y)]
  classify :: [(x,y)] -> c -> x > y
```

Here, `train` is getting a list of samples of type `x`, a list of labels of type `y`, and a classifier of some type `c`, and needs to return a list of sample/label pairs.

`classify` takes a list of sample/label pairs (such as that produced by `train`), the classifier, and a sample, and produces a new label.

(At the very least, though, I'd probably replace `[(x,y)]` with something like `Map x y`.)

The key is that the classifier itself needs to be used by both `train` and `classify`, although you don't need to know what that would look like at this time.

Your instance for `KNN` could then look like

```
instance Classifier KNN where

  train samples labels (KNN n f) = ...
  classify td (KNN n f) sample = ...
```

Here, `n` and `f` can be used both to create the training data, and to help pick the closest member of the training data for a sample point.

Comment: A classifier that can work with every type of samples and labels is probably too generic to be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect a type family (or multiparameter type class with functional dependencies) to constrain the sample and label types that can be used with a given classifier would be better, but I don't know the domain well enough to provide a suggestion. This at least works with `KNN` as defined.